# How much does the Vitamin D3 concentration of the blood of a human change over the course of a day?

Tags: vitamins

Are there studies that measured how much the blood concentration of Vitamin D3 changes over the course of a day? If so, how strongly does it change? Does it change in predictable patterns?

Comment: Did you check on Pubmed?